# trying to install hmmlearn but getting is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip, hmmlearn

I am trying to install hmmlearn however I am having issues.

My version of python,

> Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36)

I have checked that my pip is up to date as well.

> c:\users\xxx\pip install c:\users\xxx\documents\code\python\hmmlearn-0.2.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

I get the error message

> hmmlearn-0.2.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

I have also tried the file hmmlearn-0.2.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64 and get the same error message.

How do I install hmmlearn?

**Update**

Last week I downloaded PyCharm on my computer have no idea if this will have created an issue?